# Connect to A VPN from Azure Synapse Pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory, vpn, azure-synapse

We are working on a data integration task, where the vendor provides access to their API's through a VPN and Client Certification. Is there any method available to connect the VPN from Azure Synapse?

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: Could you include more details like what you tried and where you stuck by editing your question and error images? –

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to systems that are onPremise, you need to use a self-hosted  integration runtime for this task:
[image]
Then in you select the self-hosted-integration-runtime as "worker" in your datasets like this:

[image]

Here you can create it:
[image]

Here's some documentation (they explain here for data factory, but for synapse it's the same concept): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory